# Full Outer Join and Null Values: The # of successful medical attentions per Year pear Doctor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a database of a (fictitious) hospital. I have the following tables:

```
Admission --Name Table
Adm_ID  --Number of the reception
Pat_ID --Id Patient
Date_Adm --Date reception
Date_Discharge --Discharge Date from the hospital
Health_ID --Health at the moment of discharge


Adm_Med --Name Table
Adm_ID
Med_ID --ID Medical Procedure carried out
Doc_ID --ID Doctor who carried that out.
```

And I want to make a table that shows the number of successful medical attention per year for each of the doctors. Successful medical attention is define by `Health_ID =20` (`20` is the code for `Healthy`)

My attempt:

There are medical admissions from 1996 to 2001. To make it easy I began with two years only: 1996 and 1997. First I created two separate tables: one that gives the numbers of successful attention in the year 1996 and the other for 1997. For instance for 1996:

```
SELECT Doc_ID, COUNT(aID) as [Successful 1996]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT a.Adm_ID as aID, Doc_ID, YEAR(Date_Discharge) as yr, Health_ID
        FROM Admission a, Adm_Med am
        WHERE a.Adm_ID=am.Adm_ID
        AND year(date_discharge)=1996
        AND Health_ID=20
    ) temp2
    GROUP BY Doc_ID
```

And the result of the two separate tables is:

[image]

Then I tried to join them:

```
SELECT T1.Doc_ID, [Successful 1996], [Successful 1997]
FROM 
(
    SELECT Doc_ID, COUNT(aID) as [Successful 1996]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT a.Adm_ID as aID, Doc_ID, YEAR(Date_Discharge) as yr, Health_ID
        FROM Admission a, Adm_Med am
        WHERE a.Adm_ID=am.Adm_ID
        AND year(date_discharge)=1996
        AND Health_ID=20
    ) temp2
    GROUP BY Doc_ID
) T1

FULL OUTER JOIN

(
    SELECT Doc_ID, COUNT(aID) as [Successful 1997]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT a.Adm_ID as aID, Doc_ID, YEAR(Date_Discharge) as yr, Health_ID
        FROM Admission a, Adm_Med am
        WHERE a.Adm_ID=am.Adm_ID
        AND year(date_discharge)=1997
        AND Health_ID=20
    ) temp2
    GROUP BY Doc_ID

) T2
ON T1.Doc_ID=T2.Doc_ID
```

And gives

[image]

As can be see, the line seven gives a successful medical att. in `1997` but with `NULL Doc_ID` for that line, when it should be the `Doc_ID` with number `82`.

I think there a problem with the `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but as a beginner I can't figure out why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: you got Doc_ID from T1 and in T1 table there is no Doc_ID=82

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shown leftmost column is derived from `T1.Doc_ID`. But your subquery T1 does not return a row for those doctors that have no admission in 1996.

Change your query this way:

```
SELECT coalesce(T1.Doc_ID, T2.Doc_ID), [Successful 1996], [Successful 1997]
...
```

This way, the doctor id is taken either from T1 or T2 based on where it is not null.

Comment: Although it solves your issue @NineBerry solution is way better performance wise and does not require an additional query and JOIN for every year, only an additional column.

Comment: P.s. and @GordonLinoff would have said: **"Learn to use proper JOIN syntax. Simple rule: Never use commas in the FROM clause."**

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to want to create a lot of columns for a lot of different years, using a subquery for every year and joining them, might not be such a good idea. Instead, you can use one query and create the different columns by filtering / counting in the select clause itself like this:

```
SELECT Doc_ID, 
  Sum(CASE WHEN year(date_discharge)=1996 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Successful 1996],
  Sum(CASE WHEN year(date_discharge)=1997 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Successful 1997],
  Sum(CASE WHEN year(date_discharge)=1998 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Successful 1998]
  -- And so forth
  FROM Admission a, Adm_Med am
  WHERE a.Adm_ID=am.Adm_ID
  AND Health_ID=20

GROUP BY Doc_ID
```

(Code not tested)

Comment: Wow! You hit the nail on the head with this. Once looking at your first answer and going back to my code,I realized what a headache would be to repeat the query for every year. This has prevented me from doing so. I will read more about the `CASE` statement. I had no idea about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that you use aggregation for this.  NineBerrys approach is pretty close, but I would write it like this:

```
    SELECT ad.Doc_ID,
           SUM(CASE WHEN year(a.date_discharge) = 1996 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Successful_1996,
           SUM(CASE WHEN year(a.date_discharge) = 1997 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Successful_1997,
           SUM(CASE WHEN year(a.date_discharge) = 1998 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Successful_1998,
           . . .
    FROM Adm_Med am LEFT JOIN
         Admission a, 
         ON a.Adm_ID = am.Adm_ID AND a.Health_ID = 20
    GROUP BY am.Doc_ID;
```

I should note that this assumes (as does your original query) that a doctor only does one procedure per admission.  Or, to phrase it differently, this is counting procedures, not admissions or patients.

What are the differences?

- There is the cosmetic change of including qualified column names.
- More importantly, this uses a `LEFT JOIN` with the health condition in the `ON` clause.  This ensures that you get doctors with a `0` count.